# What is the delegate parameter for netsh http add urlacl

Tags: windows, http, netsh

[The documentation on how `netsh http` works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http#add-urlacl) is really sparse with hardly anything available online. We have here the `delegate` parameter which according to the docs

> Specifies one of the following values: yes: Allow the user to delegate URLs no: Deny the user from delegating URLs. This is the default value.

What on earth does that mean? What does it mean to delegate URLs? (Or for that matter Is there anywhere that explains the concepts of urlacl better?)